# warning: ‘struct user_data_s’ declared inside parameter list

Tags: c

I'm getting this error:

```
transform.c:23: warning: ‘struct user_data_s’ declared inside parameter list
transform.c:23: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
```

Which I think is because I have a struct that contains a struct.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
void f2(struct user_data_s* data) {
  printf("Number %i\n", data->L);
}

void f1(struct user_data_s* data) {
  printf("Number %i\n", data->L);
  f2(data);
}
```

The printf in f1 works, but the line

```
void f2(struct user_data_s* data) {
```

gives the error.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Show full code, including declaration of 'struct user_data_s', hugs later :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange compiler warning C: warning: ‘struct’ declared inside parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have declared your struct in between (or possibly after) your declarations of `f2` and `f1`.  Move your struct declaration so that it comes before both declarations.

That is to say:

```
struct user_data_s
{
    int L;
};

void f2(struct user_data_s* data) {
      printf("Number %i\n", data->L);
}

void f1(struct user_data_s* data) {
      printf("Number %i\n", data->L);
        f2(data);
}
```

compiles without errors, but

```
void f2(struct user_data_s* data) {
      printf("Number %i\n", data->L);
}


struct user_data_s
{
    int L;
};

void f1(struct user_data_s* data) {
      printf("Number %i\n", data->L);
        f2(data);
}
```

will not compile, because `f2` has no way to know what a `struct user_data_s` is.

You might be used to programming in a higher-level language that lets you place your declarations/definitions pretty much anywhere (such as C# or Python), but unfortunately, C is compiled strictly top-to-bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much =) I hadn't included in header file, where the struct were defined. I would never have thought of that my self.

Comment: There's also another common, yet hard to find, reason this can occur. The header file that has that struct definition, or one of its dependencies, has an error in it. The give away is usually at the bottom of the warnings list, so it can be hard to fine.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but in my case the heaser file with definition of struct is included in the very beggining, so @JonathanHenson I think this is your case, can clarify what is the bottom of the warnings list?

Answer (score 8):

The compiler already gave you a pretty good explanation of what's going on.

You haven't declared `struct user_data_s` anywhere in advance. The compiler sees `struct user_data_s` in the above function definitions for the very first time ever. In each case the declaration of `struct user_data_s` has block scope, i.e. it is local to the corresponding function. This means that the first declaration of `struct user_data_s` in the `f1` definition is completely unrelated the the second declaration of `struct user_data_s` in `f2` definition. These declarations declare two completely different local (to each function) types `struct user_data_s`. You can't call `f2` from `f1` as in your example since their parameter types are completely unrelated.

Normally, you should have `struct user_data_s` declared at file scope in advance, instead of declaring it in function definition. Did you forget to include a header with the declaration of `struct user_data_s` by any chance?

Comment: Yes =) That was exactly the problem. Forgot to include the header file =) Thank you very much for the in depth explanation. Now I will never make that mistake again =)

Answer (score 0):

Another good reason to use `typedef`, which Linus/Linux choose to avoid.

Is it legitimate to declare a structure in function arguments list?  If not, then why would the compiler think it's a structure definition?