# Strange compiler warning C: warning: ‘struct’ declared inside parameter list

Tags: c

I just found a quirk in C that I find really confusing. In C it's possible to use a pointer to a struct before it has been declared. This is a very useful feature that makes sense because the declaration is irrelevant when you're just dealing with a pointer to it. I just found one corner case where this is (surprisingly) not true, though, and I can't really explain why. To me it looks like a mistake in the language design.

Take this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


typedef void (*a)(struct lol* etc);

void a2(struct lol* etc) {

}

int main(void) {
        return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
foo.c:6:26: warning: ‘struct lol’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
foo.c:6:26: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
foo.c:8:16: warning: ‘struct lol’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
```

To remove this problem we can simply do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

struct lol* wut;

typedef void (*a)(struct lol* etc);

void a2(struct lol* etc) {

}

int main(void) {
        return 0;
}
```

The unexplainable problem is now gone for an unexplainable reason. Why?

Note that this question is about the behavior of language C (or possible the compiler behavior of gcc and clang) and not the specific example I pasted.

EDIT:

I won't accept "the order of declaration is important" as an answer unless you also explain why C would warn about using a struct pointer for the first time in a function argument list but allow it in any other context. Why would that possibly be a problem?

Comment: You should still tell it the struct exists in advance using `struct lol;`

Comment: You should first tell the compiler the exists such type as a struct lol and then you can use struct lo or a pointer to the struct in the declaration of a new function

Comment: Also it looks like the compiler explained the exact problem to you: scope. Read the warnings!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To understand why the compiler complains, you need to know two things about C "struct"s:

- they are created (as a declared, but not yet defined, type) as soon as you name them, so the very first occurrence of `struct lol` creates a declaration
- they obey the same "declaration scope" rules as ordinary variables

(`struct lol {` declares and then begins defining the structure, it's `struct lol;` or `struct lol *` or something else that does not have the open-brace that stops after the "declare" step.)

A struct type that is declared but not yet defined is an instance of what C calls an "incomplete type".  You are allowed to use pointers to incomplete types, as long as you do not attempt to follow the pointer:

```
struct lol *global_p;
void f(void) {
    use0(global_p);     /* this is OK */
    use1(*global_p);       /* this is an error */
    use2(global_p->field); /* and so is this */
}
```

You have to complete the type in order to "follow the pointer", in other words.

In any case, though, consider function declarations with ordinary `int` parameters:

```
int imin2(int a, int b); /* returns a or b, whichever is smaller */
int isum2(int a, int b); /* returns a + b */
```

Variables named `a` and `b` here are declared inside the parentheses, but those declarations need to get out of the way so that the the *next* function declaration does not complain about them being re-declared.

The same thing happens with `struct` tag-names:

```
void gronk(struct sttag *p);
```

The `struct sttag` declares a structure, and then the declaration is swept away, just like the ones for `a` and `b`.  But that creates a big problem: the tag is gone and now you can't name the structure type ever again!  If you write:

```
struct sttag { int field1; char *field2; };
```

that defines a new and different `struct sttag`, just like:

```
void somefunc(int x) { int y; ... }
int x, y;
```

defines a new and different `x` and `y` at the file-level scope, different from the ones in `somefunc`.

Fortunately, if you declare (or even define) the struct *before* you write the function declaration, the prototype-level declaration "refers back" to the outer-scope declaration:

```
struct sttag;
void gronk(struct sttag *p);
```

Now both `struct sttag`s are "the same" `struct sttag`, so when you complete `struct sttag` later, you're completing the one inside the prototype for `gronk` too.

---

Re the question edit: it would certainly have been possible to define the action of struct, union, and enum tags differently, making them "bubble out" of prototypes to their enclosing scopes.  That would make the issue go away.  But it wasn't defined that way.  Since it was the ANSI C89 committee that invented (or stole, really, from then-C++) prototypes, you can blame it on them. :-)

Comment: Thanks. I think this was the most insightful answer.

Comment: I was around when they invented these (prototype scopes, and all that).  People discovered the problem with struct declarations inside prototypes when they started using prototypes—often getting incomprehensible error messages from compilers that did the type checking, but just said `struct foo * is not compatible with struct foo *` without explaining *why*.  That was... interesting. :-)

Comment: could you provide some quotes from standard please.?

Comment: @GreenTree: which one, the original 1989 ANSI C standard, or something more recent?

Comment: @torek, C99. (doubt that wording would differ, paragraph number maybe)

Comment: @GreenTree: I only have a 201x draft handy, unfortunately (n1570). You have to synthesize the above from parts: 6.2.5 Types (pp 42-43) says that a struct or union type starts as an incomplete type that is completed by (re)declaring the same struct/union tag later in the same scope. For scopes, go to 6.2.1, Scopes of Identifiers, pp 35-36. "same scope" is determined by the *end* of the scope, and "function prototype scope" exists and is entered by reaching the `(` in the `T f(args)` and exited at the closing `)`, so that becomes the wrong scope if the type is not yet declared.

Comment: @torek, https://ideone.com/yWcO2Z from comment I understood that 'a' and 'b' should have different types, since struct goo_t from foo's prototype scope has to be completed in it.
but they would have same type, and it's problem to me to find/synthesize from std explicit rule for this case.

Comment: Well, none of those are completed (which is OK as long as the pointers are not dereferenced) but they are the same type because the inner prototype `struct goo_t` is re-using the outer scope's existing `struct goo_t` as there's no open brace in the prototype. In 6.7.2: "the presence of a struct-declaration-list ... declares a new type" so `struct goo_t;` doesn't force a new type but `struct goo_t { ... }` does.

Comment: @torek, struct goo_t; does force a new type if there is no such type already in scope. When tag is used in another declaration, like 'struct A *a;' (in form `struct A` without immediate semicolon after), in this case, if tag name space does not already contain the name, new tag is introduced (into scope), otherwise 'struct A' usage refers to tag declared in outer scope (no tag redeclaration) - n1256 6.7.2.3.(7-8) .
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct "Note that a new struct name may also be introduced..."

Comment: @GreenTree: that's why I used the phrasing "*force* a new type": `struct goo_t *p` refers to an existing one if it exists and creates a new one if not, while `struct goo_t { ... } *p` forces the creation of a new type (clashing with the existing one if it's defined at the *same* scope, or just creating a new one if we're in an inner scope). Your link goes to something else I was looking for, the so-called "vacuous declaration": a struct or union keyword followed by the tag followed by a semicolon. This one "clears out" an outer-scope one and declares a new type, rather than re-using the outer.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is warning you about a *forward declaration* of `struct lol`. C allows you to do this:

```
struct lol;     /* forward declaration, the size and members of
                   struct lol are unknown */
```

This is most used when defining self-referencing structs, but it is also useful when defining private structs that are never defined in the header. Because of this latter use case, it is allowed to declare functions that receive or return pointers to incomplete structs:

```
void foo(struct lol *x);
```

However, just using an undeclared struct in a function declaration, as you did, will be interpreted as a *local* incomplete declaration of `struct lol` whose scope is constrainted to the function. This interpretation is mandated by the C standard, but it is not useful (there is no way to construct the `struct lol` to pass to the function) and is almost certainly not what the programmer intended, so the compiler warns.

Answer (score 5):

This is because, in the first example, the struct is previously undefined and so the compiler tries to treat this first reference to that struct as a definition.

In general, C is a language where the order of your declarations matters. Everything you use should be properly declared in advance in some capacity, so that the compiler can reason about it when it's referenced in other context.

This is not a bug or a mistake in the design of the language. Rather, it's a choice that I believe was made to simplify the implementations of the first C compilers. Forward declarations allow a compiler to translate the source code serially in one pass (as long as some information such as sizes and offsets is known). If this weren't the case, the compiler would have be able to go back and forth in the program whenever it meets an unrecognized identifier, requiring its code emission loop to be much more complex.

Comment: Technically, you can still do it all in "one pass", you just have to keep a lot more data in memory.  Works out similarly in terms of simple vs complex in the compiler, of course. :-)

Comment: @torek True. I'll see if I can phrase it more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I see this same warning before. My fix is to include the proper header file which contains the definition of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, I would like to post a code example, which makes the problem more obvious. Please consider the following:

```
int testFunc(struct SomeStruct {int a; int b;} param1) // gcc: warning ...  
{
  return param1.a + param1.b;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct SomeStruct params; // gcc: error: storage size of 'params' isn't known
    params.a = 25;
    params.b = 15;
    return testFunc(params);
}
```

As you can see, the function declaration of **testFunc** is considered a valid C code (tested with GCC 12, Clang 15 and MSVC 19.32). However, you can't really use it because SomeStruct is only valid within the scope of the function, which is what compiler warns you about.

I've stumbled on this myself when working on my own C parser as the allowance of such syntax makes parser development easier as you can reuse the same implementation to parse struct declaration inside function parameter lists. It is surprising, however, that such bizarre syntax is still considered valid nowadays (as of C17) and instead of error you just get a warning.

Answer (score -1):

**Lookout for typos and DOUBLE CHECK your line numbers!** I concat all my source files before compiling, so the line numbers from the source I am working in are meaningless. I have to take extra time to open up the concatted payload and examine it. So usually I don't and I just assume I know what line I am looking at from the console output message.

Example:
GCC Says:

> EXAMPLE.C11:27:1: error: 'struct THIS_STRUCT_IS_OK' declared inside
>   parameter list [-Werror]  ){

```
#include <stdio.h> //:for: printf(...)

struct THIS_STRUCT_IS_OKAY{
    int whatever;
};


int LookingAtThisFunction(

    struct THIS_STRUCT_IS_OKAY* arg

){ 
   //:    (Because you are not checking line numbers, you    )
   //:    (assume you are looking here. But you are not.     )
   //:    (Maybe you are concatenating all of your source    )  
   //:    (files together before compiling and line numbers  )
   //:    (don't correspond to the original source and you   )
   //:    (didn't examine your concatted source code payload?)

    return( arg -> whatever );

}

//:You are not looking here because this is later in the
//:file, so the compiler would be complaining about the
//:FIRST usage of the struct, not the second one, you assume.
//:And you would be correct, if there wasn't a typo.
void WhereYouAreNotLooking(
    struct THIS_STRUCT_IS_OK* arg
){ 

    LookingAtThisFunction( arg );

}


int main( void ){

}
```

In summary: If you know what the error message means. And you swear to god
the compiler is broken because you already checked that... 
 1. Look for typos.
 2. Make sure you are really looking at the correct line number.

I get that this is kinda stupid. But it had been scratching my head for
half an hour. So hopefully it helps someone who's already looked at the
obvious solutions.