# struct’ declared inside parameter list with a header file

Tags: c

I have a simple header file with the following code:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < pthread.h >

void init(struct prodcons * b);

void put(struct prodcons * b, int data);

int get(struct prodcons * b);

void * producer(void * data);

void * consumer(void * data);
```

when I compile the terminal give this four warnings:

```
producer_consumer.h:4:18: aviso: ‘struct prodcons’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
producer_consumer.h:4:18: aviso: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
producer_consumer.h:6:17: aviso: ‘struct prodcons’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
producer_consumer.h:8:16: aviso: ‘struct prodcons’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
```

Comment: You should use `#include <stdio.h>`, not `#include < stdio.h >`; likewise for `<pthread.h>`.

Comment: yes I know, in the .c file I have it right. thanks. 

but if I put "struct prodcons;" int the top of the .h file, it will not give the warning?

Comment: If at all possible, you should copy-and-paste your exact code rather than re-typing it, so we don't waste time on problems that turn out to be just typos. Adding `struct prodcons;` should correct the problem, but the type has to be fully defined somewhere; unless you need to hide the internals, you might as well put the full definition in this header (or in something that it `#include`s).

Comment: If you're not going to include the structure's real header file, you can still squelch this message by putting `struct prodcons;` above any usage, thereby forward-declaring the incomplete type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange compiler warning C: warning: ‘struct’ declared inside parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `struct prodcons` somewhere. Right now there's no declaration for it, so the compiler is inferring it.

Presumably you have a declaration for this in another file -- if it's in another header, add an `#include` directive for it to the top of this .h file, before all the functions that use it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains about the missing declaration of "struct prodcons". You have to include a header file that actually gives a declaration of that struct, or you have to insert a forward declaration of that struct, like just writing:

```
struct prodcons;
```

Comment: "struct prodcons;" in the top of the header file?

Comment: Just anywhere before it's used in the function declarations, like directly before function `init()`.

But you probably have to search for and include the file where `struct prodcons` is actually defined, because you likely want to use those functions, and therefore have to know how to fill that struct.

Comment: the struct prodcons is defined in a .c file called producer_consumer.c, so I have to do an include of that .c file in this header file?

for example before init();

#include "producer_consumer.c" ??

Comment: Now I understand: This is your header file, and `struct prodcons` is defined in your .c file. You need to copy the definition of it in your header file, before those functions that use it. Of course you also need to copy all further definitions that may be used inside that struct.

Best practice is to only have that struct defined in your header file (not anymore in your .c file) and include that header file in your .c file as well. This way, if you change the signature of one of your functions or the insides of the struct, you will get a compiler error if you didn't change the header too.

Comment: So I have the definiton of the structure like :

structure prodcons {

variables....

};

and than I declare the structure variable : struct prodcons p;

I have to put this two things only in the header file or just the definition?

Comment: You don't need to copy the definition. just do as this says, placing `struct prodcons;` somewhere above the first prototype the uses a pointer-to-struct as a parameter. The implementation file that formally defines it, assuming its the only file that needs that definition, can do what it does now: `struct prodcons { ... };`, completing the incomplete type before its actual use. In other words, this answer should work as-written. So long as your api's only need pointers, this will work.

Comment: just putting the struct prodcons is not working, give the sames warnings

Comment: @AlexandreSilva They are not the same warning messages. If the are, then you're compiler is brain-dead, because the first-decl is clearly no longer in the parameter list. Your file should have `struct prodcons; void init(struct prodcons * b); etc...`. Check the spelling, and the *placement* and make sure the *only* header-level access to that structure is in these functions prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

`struct prodcons` has not been defined anywhere. You need to define it before those prototypes, or `#include` a header file that defines it.

Since the parameter list is the first time the compiler has seen `struct prodcons`, it assumes that you are declaring it there (which makes no sense).