# Compiler complains of conflicting types

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

I'm attempting to build a linked list but I'm getting the following error when compiling my code:

```
In file included from linkedlist.c:1:
linkedlist.h:9: warning: 'struct list_t' declared inside parameter list
linkedlist.h:9: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
linkedlist.h:12: warning: 'struct list_t' declared inside parameter list
linkedlist.c: In function 'main':
linkedlist.c:11: warning: passing argument 2 of 'execute_choice' from incompatible pointer type
linkedlist.c: At top level:
linkedlist.c:28: error: conflicting types for 'execute_choice'
linkedlist.h:9: error: previous declaration of 'execute_choice' was here
linkedlist.c:56: error: conflicting types for 'create_node_in_linked_list'
linkedlist.h:12: error: previous declaration of 'create_node_in_linked_list' was here
linkedlist.h:9: warning: 'struct list_t' declared inside parameter list
linkedlist.h:9: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
linkedlist.h:12: warning: 'struct list_t' declared inside parameter list
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

However, I checked both my source file and header file, and the 'execute_choice' function had matching declarations in both.  Here are my source and header files:

**Source file:**

```
#include "linkedlist.h"

int main (void)
{
    int choice;
    list_t* list;
    list = (list_t*)sizeof(list_t);

    while (1) {
        choice = display_menu_choices();
        execute_choice(choice, list);
    }
}

int display_menu_choices(void)
{
    int menu_choice;

    printf ("Please select from the following options\n");
    printf ("0. Exit program\n");
    printf ("1. Generate a linkedlist\n");
    printf ("2. Sort a linkedlist\n");
    scanf ("%d", &menu_choice);

    return menu_choice;
}

void execute_choice(int menu_choice, list_t* list)
{
    switch (menu_choice) {
        case GEN_LL:
        generate_linked_list();
        break;

        case SORT_LL:
        sort_linked_list();
        break;

        case EXIT:
        exit(0);
    }

    return;
}

void generate_linked_list(void)
{
    return;
}

void sort_linked_list(void)
{
    return;
}

void create_node_in_linked_list(list_t* list)
{
    return;
}
```

**Header:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define EXIT 0
#define GEN_LL 1
#define SORT_LL 2

int display_menu_choices(void);
void execute_choice(int, struct list_t*);
void generate_linked_list(void);
void sort_linked_list(void);
void create_node_in_linked_list(struct list_t*);

typedef struct node_t{
    struct node_t* current;
    struct node_t* next;
    int value;
} node_t;

typedef struct list_t{
    struct node_t* start;
} list_t;
```

Also, tips in general are welcome!  Please critique my code however  you feel necessary - I'll never learn from my mistakes if nobody points them out =)  Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks like C, not C++. Which compiler are you using, on which system?

Comment: `typedef` move to before prototypes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list One of the first results of a search for your first warning message.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the type before you try to use it.

So if you move the struct definitions/typedefs before the function prototypes, the compiler should stop complaining about implicit/conflicting definitions.

Answer (score 2):

The order of things inside your header file is wrong. The `typedef` should appear before the function definitions. So move

```
typedef struct node_t{
  struct node_t* current;
  struct node_t* next;
  int value;
} node_t;

typedef struct list_t{
  struct node_t* start;
} list_t;
```

before

```
int display_menu_choices(void);
void execute_choice(int, struct list_t*);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping - compiled successfully!