# "warning: 'struct matrix' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]" and error: conflicting types for 'scanToken'

Tags: c, struct, gcc-warning

I've been pouring over this issue trying to figure out what is causing these errors, but so far I've come up with nothing. I have this function:

```
    struct token scanToken(struct matrix refTable){
        struct token send;
        int counter = 0;
        int currState = refTable.start;
        while (1) {
                printf("%d ", currState);
                char c = getchar();
                send.buffer[counter] = c;
                int class = classifyChar(c);
                char result = refTable.grid[class][currState].action;
                currState = refTable.grid[class][currState].nextState;
                if (currState = 99){
                        findEnd();
                        send.recrej = 'd';
                        return send;
                }
                else if (currState = refTable.accept){
                        if (c == EOF){
                                send.isEnd = 't';
                        }
                        else{
                                send.isEnd = 'f';
                                send.recrej = 'a';
                        }
                }
                ++counter;
        }
        return send;
}
```

It is matched with the following header file:

```
  struct token {
        char buffer[512];
        char recrej;
        char isEnd;
};


void findEnd(void);

struct token scanToken(struct matrix refTable);

int classifyChar(char c);
```

This code is currently used in this snippet in my main function:

```
 struct matrix table;
        table = buildMatrix(argv[1]);
        char c;
        int class;
        struct token found;
        found = scanToken(table);
        while(found.isEnd != 't'){
                if (found.recrej == 'a'){
                        printf("recognized '%s'\n", found.buffer);
                }
                else {
                        printf("rejected\n");
                }
                found = scanToken(table);
        }
```

the matrix struct is prototyped in another header file, which is included in the scanner.c file (pictured first), and the tokenize.c file (pictured last). However, this produces the following warnings and errors.

```
In file included from scanner.c:10:0:
scanner.h:16:31: warning: 'struct matrix' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 struct token scanToken(struct matrix refTable);
                               ^
scanner.h:16:31: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
scanner.c:60:14: error: conflicting types for 'scanToken'
 struct token scanToken(struct matrix refTable){
              ^
In file included from scanner.c:10:0:
scanner.h:16:14: note: previous declaration of 'scanToken' was here
 struct token scanToken(struct matrix refTable);
```

I've been searching for quite some time, and have tried rewriting things a number of ways, with the same result all around. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any `#ifdef`s or similar surrounding the definition of `struct matrix`? Looks a lot like the include isn't working.

Comment: There are no #ifdefs used. Unfortunately that might've been an easy fix, but its not what's causing it.

Comment: Create a new .c file, and copy and paste all the relevant code into it, including your header files. If it works then, there is some problem with the #includes.

Comment: The act of passing full structs, rather than simply a pointer to a struct, results in such structs being allocated in 'work' areas by the linker.  Then the original struct is copied to the work area (and probably, depending on the code written, copied back to its' original location).  I suggest 1) actually define the format of the struct matrix in a header file 2) #include that header file. 3) pass two parameters to the scanmatrix function one for the current struct and one for the struct currently being returned.  use a void return.

Comment: the result of implementing the above comment is: This would eliminate your current code problems, eliminate the wasted ram where the 'work' area is allocated, greatly speed up the execution by eliminating all the calls to memcpy, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange compiler warning C: warning: ‘struct’ declared inside parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list)

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `struct matrix` outside a function prototype, like the error message implies.

You have in your `scanner.h` header:

```
struct token scanToken(struct matrix refTable);
```

Since there's no prior declaration of `struct matrix` in that header, or a header read before it is read, the `struct matrix` is a new distinct type.  It's also incomplete, so you really need to use a pointer to it.

You can fix it as simply as:

```
struct matrix;
struct token scanToken(struct matrix *refTable);
```

To be able to pass the `struct matrix` by value instead of by pointer, you need a full definition of the structure, but pointers can be passed to incomplete types.

Or include the header that defines the `struct matrix` fully in the `scanner.h` header.

Note that you should protect your headers with multiple inclusion guards:

```
#ifndef SCANNER_H_INCLUDED
#define SCANNER_H_INCLUDED

…current contents…

#endif // SCANNER_H_INCLUDED
```

You might well add `#include "otherheader.h"` in that one — the other header that defines `struct matrix` in full.