# why do I have to declare an irrelevant struct file_handle variable before I can use that type?

Tags: c, linux

Following the documentation for Linux `open_by_handle_at`() :

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open_by_handle_at.2.html

I write this C file:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

typedef void (*foobar) (struct file_handle *);
```

but it compiles with an ominous warning:

```
>gcc -c foobar.c
warning: ‘struct file_handle’ declared inside parameter list
```

If I add an irrelevant declaration in between:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct file_handle *junk;

typedef void (*foobar) (struct file_handle *);
```

then it compiles without a warning.  Why the warning??

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Strange compiler warning C: warning: ‘struct’ declared inside parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list#16831856).

Comment: @halfbit well, according to the documentation I quoted, the header files should have the declaration

Comment: Just as a note: I cannot reproduce your warning on my linux box running openSUSE 13.2. The definition seems to be pulled in via `#include <fcntl.h>` including `/usr/src/include/bits/fcntl.h` including `/usr/src/include/bits/fcntl-linux.h`, the latter containing the struct definition at line 311 (in an `#ifdef __USE_GNU` which should result from `_GNU_SOURCE`).

Comment: "It compiles without a warning" but surely it will throw errors when you attempt to use the struct members later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared `struct file_handle` anywhere in advance. The compiler sees `struct file_handle` in the above function definitions for the very first time ever. In each case the declaration of `struct file_handle` has block scope, i.e. it is local to the corresponding function.

Add the below structure before your function.

```
 struct file_handle {
     unsigned int  handle_bytes;   /* Size of f_handle [in, out] */
     int           handle_type;    /* Handle type [out] */
     unsigned char f_handle[0];    /* File identifier (sized by caller) [out] */
 };
```

Higher-level language lets you place your declarations/definitions pretty much anywhere (such as C++ or Python), but unfortunately, C is compiled from top-to-bottom.

Comment: well, according to the documentation I quoted, those header files should have the declaration in them

Comment: As far as I remember even if you have a header file included you still have to do a `typedef struct structname;`  followed by `structname instance` before using it

Comment: You definitely do not have to do that.

Comment: @yanivx  yes these headers do_not have that definition in them, as they should I think according to documentation.  I checked with the preprocessor.  Where did you get your structure definition from??

Comment: @MarkGaleck I got it from the link you shared it has the definition of this structure in the description section.

Comment: @yanivx indeed right you are - I did not see that.  Well, I still don't understand why it is not in the headers, but yes your answer solves the problem

Comment: @MarkGaleck It is defined in `fs.h` header file try including this file which has this structure definition at line no 839  here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L839