# c compiler warning: 'struct x' declared inside parameter list

Tags: c, struct

This question has been asked before, but none of the solutions seem to apply to my code. Here is my main file `server.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "message.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my included file `message.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct message_t {
    int field1;
    int field2;
};

int sendMessage(struct message_t *message) {
    // do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

I also have a header file `message.h`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct message_t {
    int field1;
    int field2;
};

int sendMessage(struct message_t *message);
```

When I compile server.c and message.c, I get this warning for `message.c` at the line where I declare `sendMessage`:
    warning: 'struct message_t' declared inside parameter list
    warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want

What does it mean 'declared inside parameter list'? What is the parameter list it refers to?

Comment: For which file and which line you get the warning ? And why do you define `struct message_t` in message.c ? You should rather include message.h.

Comment: ... and which line ? Edit your question and don't post comments.-

Comment: Remove the declaration `struct message_t {
    int field1;
    int field2;
};` from all files but  `message.h`. And include message.h in your .c files. Then it should compile.

Comment: Which compiler do you use ? The error message you get doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your help! I'm using gcc

Comment: The code you have posted, `server.c` should complain about redefinition of `struct message_t` Are you sure this code is *exactly* what you were compiling?

Comment: You're right, I removed the redefinition from 'server.c'. I edited it so it's correct now.

Comment: The code that you posted will not generate this warning. It would only if you remove the declaration from message.c (problem explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list) ). Please edit your question to make it less confusing, and i will remove my downvote.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Please make sure that the code you post reproduces the problem you're asking about.  Around here, that's called creating an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), though it's sometimes referred to as an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  The code in the question doesn't reproduce the problem asked about.

Comment: I note in passing that `message.h` has no reason to include either `<stdlib.h>` or `<unistd.h>` — the file can be included on its own whether those headers are included or not.  A header should be self-contained (able to be included without any other headers having to be included first), and should be idempotent (protected against multiple inclusioin — usually with the `#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED` / `#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED` / `#endif` dance).  Idempotency isn't critical for a minimal header in a question like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are defining `message_t` in three places, when you should only define it in message.h. Also, message.c should include message.h.

Comment: This wouldn't make a difference (`#include` is a plain text replacement), unless the 'real code' was not exactly as OP has posted

Comment: @M.M but it is best practice to do so as it allows more bugs to be detected at compile-time.