# Do parameter declarations in function declarators have function prototype scope?

Tags: c, scope, language-lawyer, c11

Clause 6.2.1(2) of the C11 ISO Standard (draft) defines a function prototype as (emphasis mine)

> A function prototype is a **declaration of a function** that declares the types of its parameters.

So a declaration such as `void (*f)( struct s { int c; } );`
is not a declaration of a function (it is a declaration of a pointer to a function) and thus the tag `s` has either file or block scope (depending on where this declaration appears). It would then seem that the following translation unit `void (*f)( struct s { int c; } ); struct s a[42];`
should be fully conforming (setting aside any issues of usability). Yet, `gcc` produces a diagnostic 'array of incomplete types' (and a warning about `s` having the scope confined to the parameter list) signaling that `s` has a function prototype scope even though formally there is no function declaration.

Was the intention of the Standard to say that a parameter list in every function **declarator** defines its own scope (which is how `gcc` and every other compiler seem to interpret this)? Is this intention expressed more formally anywhere in the standard? Any Defect Report that has not made it into the Standard yet?

This is a language lawyer question, of course, and I do appreciate that such 'sneaky' tag declarations are bad style. Aside from `s` being an incomplete type in the declaration of `a` above, the scoping issues also make it impossible to *define* a function with the prototype of `*f`. Finally, to avoid the issue of using `f` itself one may put the whole declaration of `f` inside a `sizeof` as in `int b[sizeof(void (*)( struct s { int c; } ))];`

Comment: What is hard to understand about "`warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want`"?  Your prototype declares both a _parameter type_ and the _type definition_ itself - syntactically valid, but practically useless..

Comment: @Clifford: Check the [language-lawyer] tag. The warning is not hard to understand, but is it right? If so, why? Why is the scope so small?

Comment: @Clifford: to nitpick somewhat, the `struct` is not *entirely* useless since one may define a function with the appropriate prototype, and even call it *in a different translation unit*,  according to 6.2.7(1) although such practice is more than questionable. The question is whether `gcc` follows the Standard, not why it throws this warning.

Comment: @MSalters :  I appreciate the tag, that is why I posted a comment not an answer.  My point was simply that the question states _"the tag s has either file or block scope"_, while clearly it has _declaration scope_.  Possibly a near duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831605/strange-compiler-warning-c-warning-struct-declared-inside-parameter-list

Comment: @Clifford: 1) there is no *declaration scope* defined by the standard; 2) moreover, the is no *function declaration* anywhere in the example, thus, according to the language in 6.2.1(2) there is no *function prototype scope*. `gcc`'s approach is very reasonable but *does it conform to the Standard as written*?

Comment: @Clifford: Definitely related, but that's not a [language-lawyer] question. A proper answer here would show which part of C11 makes the tag `s` have _declaration scope_ ("would", because alexsh is correct. C11 has 4 types of scope, and _declaration scope_ isn't one of them)

Comment: @alexsh: A compiler is allowed to issue warnings about constructs which conform to the standard. GCC issues many such warnings (if asked to). Nothing in the standard constrains the compiler from *warning* you about things which seem important to it (even warnings like "you've been working on this problem too long; take a break" would be conformant.) (See footnote 9 on page 12: "Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated.")

Comment: @MSalters : Indeed the term is not defined in the language - I made it up.  It has "block-scope", but the block ends at the end of the declaration (at the semi-colon).   I think - which is why I am not answering.  I simply chose to describe that special case as _declaration scope_. Will steer well clear of such questions in future and get on with some real work!

Comment: @rici: My issue is not with the warning (it is more than reasonable). It is with the *error* that results from `struct s` being incomplete in the declaration of `a`. If `s` has file scope (as the Standard seems to imply it should), this translation unit should be conforming and issue no diagnostics (aside from optional warnings).

Comment: Yes, exactly, it *does not* appear inside a function prototype as defined in 6.2.1(2) unless there is *another* definition of 'function prototype' somewhere in the Standard.

Answer (score 2):

In the course of a long discussion in the comments, it became clear that this question is really about the precise meaning of the parenthetical comment in §6.2.1/2, "A *function prototype* is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters."

As far as I can see, there is no formal definition of the phrase "function prototype" and it is used in a variety of ways in the standard. For example:

1. §6.2.7/3 Compatible type and composite type:

   > If only one type is a function type with a parameter type list (a function prototype), the composite type is a function prototype with the parameter type list.

   In this case, the first usage of "function prototype" is evidently not restricted to a function declaration, since it says "function type" -- which might be the type implicitly created during the resolution of a pointer-to-function declarator -- and the second usage of "function prototype" might not have a syntactic representation at all, since it is a type created in the course of the composite-type algorithm
2. §6.5.2.2 Function calls

   Here, paragraph 2 applies to functions with a "type that includes a prototype" while paragraph 6 contrasts functions with a "type that does not include a prototype" with functions with a "type that includes a prototype". These usages are incompatible with the "definition" of "function prototype" above, because that definition applies to the function type as a whole, whereas the usage here of "prototype" is clearly talking about a part of the function type.
3. §6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)

   This section title could be interpreted as either being about all "function declarators" including those which happen to be "prototypes", or being about both "function declarators" and the "prototypes" which might be included.
4. §6.9.1/7 Function definitions

   > If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the list also specifies the types of all the parameters; such a declarator also serves as a function prototype for later calls to the same function in the same translation unit.

   Here the phrase "function prototype" seems to be talking about something associated with or contained in the function type, but for which the function declarator can be used as a proxy ("serves as").

I suppose that this would not pass the standards of formal rigour of a work such as [*Principia Mathematica*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Principia_Mathematica_54-43.png), but it is on par with most juridical specifications and with other standards, in which a modicum of common sense is necessary to interpret some passages.

Indeed, the very quote in question:

> "A *function* prototype is a declaration of a function that **declares the types** of its parameters."

implies that the parameters in a parameter list are type *declarations* and not just *specifications* (if, indeed, there is a difference between the two phrases).

Also, if we deconstruct §6.2.1/4 (quoted in part below), we see that it says that:

> **Every** other identifier [that is, other than a label or macro name] has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier).

and then proceeds to list only three alternatives for "the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier":

1. "appears outside of any block or list of parameters"
2. "appears inside a block" or "within the list of parameter declarations in
   a function definition"
3. "appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function definition)"

Those three possibilities are assumed to be exclusive (so that the provisions are not ordered) and comprehensive (since they must apply to "every identifier"). Common sense must then lead us to the assumption that a function prototype is a function declarator which includes a parameter-list, or (in some contexts) some subset or semantic abstraction from that syntactic construct, so the answer to your first question is "Yes, that is the intention of the standard".

Whether or not this is a defect in the standard is a question of opinion in which I don't choose to participate. I checked what I believe to be the  most current list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2244.htm) and saw nothing relevant, so as far as I know it has not been reported as a defect.

---

Some version of my original answer follows in case it's useful to people reading the comments.

What the standard says about the scope of identifiers in parameter lists seems quite clear to me. §6.2.1/4 defines two possible scopes for identifiers declared in a parameter list (emphasis added):

> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations **in a function definition**, the identifier has *block scope*, which terminates at the end of the associated block.
>
> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (**not part of a function definition**), the identifier has *function prototype scope*, which terminates at the end of the function declarator. (§6.2.1/4)

In the example in the question, the declarator of the `struct s` appears a *parameter-list* which is precisely "the list of parameter declarations". So the second sentence applies and their scope is confined to the parameter list itself. That makes the `struct` effectively useless, so the compiler warns you.

If the struct type specifier appeared in the parameter list of a definition, it could be used inside the function body, but no instance of that struct could be passed to the function from the translation unit in which the definition appears.

I believe that the intention of the standard was that the declaration of type specifiers for tagged types appear outside of parameter lists. This is reinforced by the language of §6.7.2.3 (Tags):

> 1. A specific type shall have its content defined at most once.

And

> 5. Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types. Each declaration of a structure, union, or enumerated type which does not include a tag declares a distinct type.

Answer (score 1):

Let take it first to an analogy

```
struct foo* x;
```

declares a pointer to `struct foo`, but still `struct foo` in that declaration is the (forward) declaration of a `struct` type.

Now

```
int (*f)(int);
```

is the declaration of a function pointer. The pointer is a pointer to base type `int ()(int)` that is of a function type with prototype.

Then

```
int (*g)(struct toto { int a; });
```

again is the declaration of a function pointer. The pointer is a pointer to base type `int ()(struct toto { int a; })` that is of a function type with prototype.

Or to summarize, a declaration of a pointer to something also declares that something to which the pointer points.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. A declaration declares an identifier. In this example, `g` is an identifier which is declared as a _pointer to function_ type. If that would _also_ declare the function type, there would have to be a second name.

Comment: That *... still struct foo in that declaration is the (forward) declaration of a struct type ...* is the subject of 6.7.2.3(6). The corresponding portion of the Standard referring to declarators (6.7.6) includes no such language, however, about declarators (`struct ...` is a type specifier) and instead very carefully uses the term *specify* (*not* declare) when referring to various types of declarators.

Comment: @alexsh: But in the second next clause, it uses the words <<A **declaration** of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’>>

Comment: @rici: *A declaration of a parameter* is a valid grammatical concept. C11 even introduces a concept of 'type name scope' to specifically deal with type names so it can treat nameless parameters as declarations. However, In my example above, *there is no function declaration*, as a parameter, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> So a declaration such as `void (*f)( struct s { int c; } );` is not a declaration of a function (it is a declaration of a pointer to a function)...

I do not agree.

Clause 6.7.6 Declarators contains:

> Syntax
>
> - declarator:
>
>   pointer<sub>opt</sub> direct-declarator
> - direct-declarator:
>         identifier
>         ( declarator )
>         direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> assignment-expressionopt ]
>         direct-declarator [ static type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> assignment-expression ]
>         direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]
>         direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> * ]
>         direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
>         direct-declarator ( identifier-list<sub>opt</sub> )
> - pointer:
>         * type-qualifier-listopt
>         * type-qualifier-list<sub>opt</sub> pointer
>   ...

My understanding of that clause is that `void (*f)( struct s { int c; } );` is indeed a pointer declaration, but that pointer declaration *includes* a function prototype definition in its *direct-declarator* part. So all the semantics of a function prototype definition apply.

So the scope of `struct s` **is** the function prototype declaration of the direct declarator part of the pointer declaration. And §4 of 6.2.1 says:

> If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears
>   within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function
>   definition), the identifier has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   function declarator.

We are exactly in that case (no definition), so the scope of the declaration of `struct s` ends at the end of the line.

So gcc is perfectly right when it produces a diagnostic 'array of incomplete types' (and a warning about s having the scope confined to the parameter list) signaling that s has a function prototype scope even though formally there is no function declaration.

Comment: As I write at the beginning of my question, the concept of 'function prototype' is defined in the Standard as a '...function **declaration** ...' (not **declarator**). The Standard does not have any language about one declaration *including* another, however tempting such an interpretation must be. Moreover (and I am nitpicking here), there is no such thing as 'function prototype definition' mentioned in the Standard. No prototype, no scope.

Comment: @alexsh: 6.7.6 §3 defines a *full declarator* as *a declarator that is not part of another declarator*. The intend is clear here.

Comment: Indeed, the intent for nesting of *declarators* is clear. *Declarations* are another matter, though.

Answer (score -2):

Actually parameters or arguments is the 1 of the part of the Prototype of a function .
Prototype of a function has 3 main components..these are
1. Function type
2. Function name
3. Arguments or parameters