# Does a struct declaration live after the scope where it was declared, if the scope was a different struct definition?

Tags: c, struct, syntax, declaration

So I've been getting the following warning after having made some changes to the code:

```
warning: declaration of 'struct Thing' will not be visible
      outside of this function
```

[This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831951/3284878) cleared up the issue.

I then became puzzled by something else. It turns out that the following was my program before the bug:

```
struct OtherThing {
    struct Thing* t; // <-- struct Thing declared here
};

void func(struct Thing* t);

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the program which raises the warning:

```
struct OtherThing {
    int t; // <-- struct Thing no-longer declared here
};

void func(struct Thing* t);

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
```

If I understand this correctly - as explained in the linked answer, a `struct` declaration declared inside a function signature has the same scoping rules as an ordinary variable.

*But* - a `struct` declaration which is declared inside a different `struct` definition *does live on after the ending '}'*?

Is my understanding correct? If so - than it isn't true that the same scoping rules apply for `struct` declarations and ordinary variables (opposed to a statement made by the linked answer). What is the logic behind this design?

Comment: The code you show us does not make your question clear. However, using `struct Thing* t`, i.e. a pointer to a thing without that the thing has been fully declared is allowed. The compiler expects it to be declared later. Anything declared in a function has function scope. A struct declared in another struct has the scope of that other struct.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Please see my edit - I believe it makes the question clearer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : in C, all structure tag names are at usable outside the defining structure; they are not given nested scopes as they are in C++.  It’s yet another difference between the two languages.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Structure tag names do have nested scopes, but the scopes are associated with blocks (compound statements), not with structure declarations. The tag name is known outside the structure because it is visible in the enclosing block (or in file scope) and is in the tag name space (in contrast to the members, which are not known outside the structure because they are in the name space particular to the structure).

Answer (score 2):

> Does a struct declaration live after the scope where it was declared, if the scope was a different struct definition?

That question has a false premise. A structure definition is not a scope, so the scope of a structure declaration cannot be an enclosing structure declaration. The scope for a structure declaration must be file scope, function prototype scope, or block scope, by C 2018 6.2.1. (There is also a function scope, but only labels [for `goto` statements] have function scope.) If the declaration is outside any function, it has function scope. If it is inside the parameters of a function prototype (not a definition), it has function prototype scope. Otherwise, it has block scope.

A block in C is:

- A compound statement (C 2018 6.8.2 2).
- A selection statement (`if`, `if…else`, or `switch`) (C 2018 6.8.4 3).
- Each associated substatement of a selection statement (*ibid*).
- An iteration statement (`while`, `do`, `for`) (C 2018 6.8.5 5).
- The loop body of a selection statement (*ibid*).

The structure declaration is not one of these and does not form a scope—the braces that bound a structure declaration are not a block that is associated with scope. The braces and declarations inside a structure declaration do not form a compound statement because it is not sufficient merely to have this form. A compound statement must also appear in a program where a statement may appear, per the C grammar in C 2018 6.8 1. The braces and declarations inside a structure declaration are part of a *struct-declaration-list* in the grammar, per C 2018 6.7.2.1 1.

So a structure declaration inside a structure declaration acts similarly to an unenclosed structure declaration—the tag declared for the structure has block scope, and the block is outside the enclosing structure declaration, so the tag is visible outside the enclosing structure.

Consider this:

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner *Member;
};
```

This declares both Outer and Inner to be structure tags. Both of them have the same scope (except for a slight difference in starting point; the scope of each starts where its name appears). If these appear outside of any function, they have file scope. If they appear inside a *block*, they have block scope. If they appear inside the parameter declarations of a function function prototype (not a definition), they have function parameter scope (but this is generally not useful for structures).

One may have the impression that scope is limited to a structure declaration because the structure member names, like `Member`, are not usable outside the structure. But this is for a different reason: structure member names are in separate name spaces. Each structure has its own name space, and its member names are in its name space. In contrast, there is only one name space for all structure/union/enumeration tags (and one name space for all ordinary identifiers, and one name space for all `goto` labels).

> What is the logic behind this design?

Originally in C, member names did not have their own name spaces—you could not have the same member names in different structures, at least not in different offsets from the structure start. Giving each structure its own name space was a valuable improvement, as declarations of different structures would not interact, and programmers would not have to worry about what member names were declared by headers they included. And this change did not change the language syntactically: Member names are always used in the context of a structure, so it was always clear which structure a member name was part of, and old code continued to work with this change.

Associating structure tags (or, similarly, type definitions) would have required changes to the language. You would need a way to specify which structure a tag was referring to. C++ does this with its `::` syntax. I cannot speak to the history of whether such changes were considered for C, but we can at least see that it would have imposed some cost and likely would have broken existing code—any code that referred to a structure tag declared inside another structure would have had to be changed to include the new specification of which structure it was referring to.

Comment: How does the fact that the `{...}` after a structure declaration is not a block arise from the C standard? I cannot find where it says "a block is a...", it only says that a block allows one to group statements and declarations. I imagine that since the `{...}` in the struct declaration disallows statements, it is not a block. Is this correct or is there a more explicit way to derive this fact from the standard?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: Actually, compound statements are not the only blocks in C, so I have updated the answer to be more thorough about this. I have also added information about why the `{…}` of a structure declaration, along with the declarations inside it, is not a block: The C standard does not say that anything with this form is a compound statement. It says (by way of its formal grammar) that, if `{…}` appears where a statement is expected (and the `…` is a list, possibly empty, of statements and declarations), then that is a block. Because the `{…}` of a structure declaration appears in…

Comment: … a structure declaration, not where a statement may appear, it is not a compound statement.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your answers are always enlightening. It bothered me somewhat that the standard only says that such and such is a block, rather than saying that "a block is...". I took a look at annex A and I now understand your point about the `{...}` being expected after a function definition.